# Show same value twice with a different THEN output in a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a case statement is it possible to show the same value with a different THEN output.

I've shown a basic example below.

```
CASE
  WHEN DateTime = '2017-03-22 10:00:00.620' THEN 1
  WHEN DateTime = '2017-03-22 10:00:00.620' THEN 2
  ELSE DateTime
END AS DateTime2
```

A process runs several times a day and gives the time an order number.  Unfortunately it can fail so in the example below the one at 08:00 on the 22nd didn't run.  So I want the one at 10:00 to have **3** as the **Order**.  I will be doing this manually in a case statement.

```
DateTime                    Order
2017-03-21 00:00:00.610     1
2017-03-21 08:00:00.467     2
2017-03-21 10:00:00.770     3
2017-03-21 13:00:00.537     4
2017-03-21 16:00:00.603     5
2017-03-21 20:00:00.110     6
2017-03-22 00:00:00.593     1
2017-03-22 10:00:00.620     2

2017-03-22 10:00:00.620     3  This time will have 2 and 3 as the order
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Add some desired output

Comment: `CASE` will show the first output and then stop. Why should it go on if it already met a `CASE` that is `true`?

Comment: Doesnt make sense to do so. Can you tell what is the exact requirement?..

Comment: The `case` expression's return types must be compatible. Integers and timestamps aren't.

Answer (score 0):

I think its answer is no. I have tested it with the sample data as given below.

```
 Create  Table #Temp(Name nvarchar(max))
 Insert Into #Temp Values('Rohit')

 Alter Table #temp Add T1 datetime

Update  #temp set T1=GETDATE()

  Select *,
   CASE
     WHEN T1 ='2017-03-22 18:17:01.780' THEN 1
        WHEN T1 = '2017-03-22 18:17:01.780' THEN 2
 END AS DateTime2
  from #Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, this will give you the exact required output

```
DECLARE @TEST_TABLE TABLE(SNO INT,COL_TIME DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @TEST_TABLE VALUES
(1,'2017-03-21 00:00:00.610'),
(2,'2017-03-21 08:00:00.467'),
(3,'2017-03-21 10:00:00.770'),
(4,'2017-03-21 13:00:00.537'),
(5,'2017-03-21 16:00:00.603'),
(6,'2017-03-21 20:00:00.110'),
(7,'2017-03-22 00:00:00.593'),
(8,'2017-03-22 10:00:00.620'),
(9,'2017-03-22 10:00:00.620')

;WITH TABLE_DATA
AS
(SELECT *,(SELECT COL_TIME FROM @TEST_TABLE T2
WHERE T2.SNO=T1.SNO+1)LAST_COL1,
    ISNULL((SELECT  CASE WHEN         CONVERT(VARCHAR,T3.COL_TIME,101)=CONVERT(VARCHAR,T1.COL_TIME,101) 
        THEN 1  ELSE 0  END FROM @TEST_TABLE T3 WHERE T3.SNO=T1.SNO-        1),1)LAST_COL FROM @TEST_TABLE T1 ) 
     ,TEST_TABLE1
     AS
     (  SELECT SNO,COL_TIME,LAST_COL,LAST_COL NUM FROM TABLE_DATA WHERE     SNO=1
    UNION ALL
        SELECT TT2.SNO,TT2.COL_TIME,TT2.LAST_COL,CASE WHEN TT2.LAST_COL=0     THEN 1     ELSE NUM+TT2.LAST_COL END FROM TEST_TABLE1 TT1 JOIN TABLE_DATA TT2
        ON TT1.SNO=TT2.SNO-1
     WHERE NUM<=100
 ) SELECT COL_TIME [DateTime],NUM [Order] FROM TEST_TABLE1
```

**Output**

```
-------------------------------------
--DateTime                  Order
-------------------------------------
2017-03-21 00:00:00.610     1
2017-03-21 08:00:00.467     2
2017-03-21 10:00:00.770     3
2017-03-21 13:00:00.537     4
2017-03-21 16:00:00.603     5
2017-03-21 20:00:00.110     6
2017-03-22 00:00:00.593     1
2017-03-22 10:00:00.620     2
2017-03-22 10:00:00.620     3
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I would however advise you to add any Identity column if available to the order by clause in the ranking function to make it a bit more consistent. Hope it helps.

```
;WITH cte_Data(DateTimes) AS
(
SELECT CAST('2017-03-21 00:00:00.610' AS DATETIME) UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-21 08:00:00.467' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-21 10:00:00.770' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-21 13:00:00.537' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-21 16:00:00.603' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-21 20:00:00.110' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-22 00:00:00.593' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-22 10:00:00.620' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-22 10:00:00.620'
)
SELECT DateTimes,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(DateTimes AS DATE) ORDER BY DateTimes ASC)  AS [Order] 
FROM cte_Data
```